# Localization for an app with video and audio

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, app-store, itunes

I have an app in the App Store, which contains some video and audio in Spanish. Now I want to create a French version and maybe an English one too.

I know how to do it by Localization preferences, but I wanted to know if there is any way to do this as 3 separate binaries, because the Spanish version is already quite heavy (170MB) due to its audio and video files.

Thanks

Comment: If you really want 3 separate binaries, you will just need to create 3  app with itunes connect and create 3 targets in your project and for each target, add files you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 3 versions on your app and make each available only on the AppStores of countries that speak that version's language, sure.

Comment: Yeah it's a good solution. I may have some trouble if I want them to have the same name, isn't it?

Comment: If your app name is not localizable, you could add a simple tagline like Tweetbot has "A Twitter Client with Personality".

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to separate audio and video?

Assuming that the video is not language specific, you may keep ONE copy of the video and have the audio track for each language separately. **Of course, you have to do some programming to play audio and video synchronously.**